# Android Studio .code for pass data between two edit texts in different activities

Tags: java, android

I have made 3 activities first one is main and putted 2 button to pass to others pages through intent.
I made intent between page 2 and page 3 for one Edit Text and it works good but if i go to main activity and choose from button to go to page3 it stops and O must go to page 2 then 3 through intent...
Main activity code for page2 and the same for 3 is

```
Intent intent =new Intent ( MainActivity.this,page2.class);   

    Page 2 code
    Intent i = new Intent (page2.this,page3.class);
    i.putExtra ("string"editText1.getText ().toString ());  

    Page3 code
    Bundle bundle = getIntent ().getExtras ();
    editText.setText (bundle.getString ("string"));
```

Comment: you can add your text into SharedPreference in Page1. then read this text from  onResume of your other activities (page2 and 3).

Comment: What error are you getting? can you post your error log? make sure you declared all activities in manifest file

Comment: Since, you have created the intent to move from mainActivity to page 2. How can you move to page 3 since you haven't mention any of the intent to perform this task. Can you share your full code or the stack trace for the error.

Comment: The main activity is page number 1 which i made 2 buttons in it to push every one individual to go to other two activities   i called them page 2 ( which i inserted diffrent edit text in it contains number in calculations of some formula) and page 3 (which contain diffrent edit text also )and i want to link number from page 2 to page 3 because every of this pages drives formula..page 1 contains only header and image and 2 buttons and page2 and 3 contains edit text and 1 button in each of them and i use those button to go next page like from 2 to 3

Comment: When pushing page 2 in main activity (page1) i go directly to page 2 and push button in page 2 to share information to  page 3 (like numbers )....the problem is when i was in page 1 and want to go page 3 in emulator it stop the program in emulator and must run it again only in case of pushing page 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are getting the string from activity 2 and when you go to activity 3 from the main activity it returns null, what you can do is to check if the bundle has empty string like this:

```
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
       editText.setText (bundle.getString ("string"));
    }
    else {
       editText.setText ("Some string");
    }
```

Comment: very good the emulator didnt stop when i preesed buttom from main activity to activity 2 after i used the condition if with bundle like your code and finaly i get transfer between main activity and other two activities in emulator with passing infromation too from page 2 and 3 ...thnx

Comment: bundle null refer to page2 activity if it was null?? or it mean if recent activity page 3 null??

Comment: this line of code is null `Bundle bundle = getIntent ().getExtras ();
    editText.setText (bundle.getString ("string"));` because you didn't pass any string from the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

I use bundle for fragments but for activities try this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
editText.setText(intent.getStringExtra("nameofstring"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If your copy-paste is well, I think there is a comma missing here:

```
i.putExtra ("string"editText1.getText ().toString ());
```

It should be:

```
i.putExtra ("string",editText1.getText ().toString ());
```

Comment: I was writting it not coping and i write the comma but the problem fixed when i used if conditions with bundle