# share data in TextView in activity one direct to calculation formula in activity two

Tags: java, android

i make app with 2 activity 1 and 2  and want to share number wrote in text view in page activity 1 direct in calculation in page activity 2 to be viewed  in text view in this page 2 (for example if first text view contains number 10 and i want to use this number in second activity in calculation like "value+10" and the result will be viewed in text view in page activity 2) without make any addition field in page 2

Comment: send this number 10 to activity 2 by using Intent

Comment: Please don't repost. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951575/android-studio-code-for-pass-data-between-two-edit-texts-in-different-activitie

Comment: I write 10 as example i need the cell contains number to pass to next activity in equation

Comment: now i want to use number in one activity field in calculation in activity two field and this different than the last question because i dont want to built another field in activity 2 to recieve that number in activity one(TextView in activity 2 = 3×value 1 in activity 1 )for example

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it in a Bundle

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putInt("something", 1);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In you OtherActivity:

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 int something;

 if (bundle != null) {
     something = bundle.getInt("something");
 }else{
     //
 }
```

This way you can pass a bunch of arguments to the next activity.

Comment: Is there any way than intent..because in intent way i must make cell (like text view)  to recieve number in it from activity one and then use ..i only need put number in activity one  in equation in activity 2

Answer (score 0):

Code In Activity1

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("number", 10);
startActivity(intent);
```

Code In Activity2

```
int number = getIntent().getIntExtra("number", 0);
```

Comment: i want to use number in one activity field in calculation in activity two field . i dont want to built another field in activity 2 to recieve that number in activity one i want this number go directly in equation in activity 2 like this (TextView in activity 2 = 3×value1 in activity 1 )for example

Comment: you can directly write (TextView in activity 2 = 3× getIntent().getIntExtra("number", 0)  in activity 1 ) otherwise you need to public static variable for accessing value